# Getting org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Invalid state INITIAL while printing pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am able to connect with mongodb from my spark job, but when I try to view the data that is being loaded from the database I get the error mentioning in the title. I am using pyspark module of Apache Spark.

The code Snippet is:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


import sys
print(sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding)

conf=SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.mongodb.input.uri','mongodb://127.0.0.1/github.users')
conf.set('spark.mongodb.output.uri','mongodb://127.0.0.1/github.users')


sc =SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext =SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.printSchema()


df = df.sort('followers', ascending = True)


df.take(1)
```